# How can I convert between hex NCRs and UTF-8 code units?

Tags: utf-8, utf

Example: the "large red circle" emoji  can be displayed in HTML using `&#x1f534;` But if I create a text file with that same emoji in it, save the file with UTF-8 encoding, and then examine it with a hex editor, I can see the emoji is represented with these four bytes: `F0 9F 94 B4`. And that is a very different number.

What's the formula to convert between the two representations? How does one derive 0xF09F94B4 from 0x1F534, and vice versa?

Comment: You're basically asking "How does UTF-8 encoding work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1f534` refers to the Unicode code point. In binary it is:

```
00000001 11110101 00110100
```

If you take a look at the [UTF-8 Bit Distribution](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#page=54) you can see how these bits plug in to UTF-8 encoding of the codepoint.

```
Scalar Value                First Byte  Second Byte Third Byte  Fourth Byte
00000000 0xxxxxxx           0xxxxxxx            
00000yyy yyxxxxxx           110yyyyy    10xxxxxx        
zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx           1110zzzz    10yyyyyy    10xxxxxx    
000uuuuu zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx  11110uuu    10uuzzzz    10yyyyyy    10xxxxxx
```

---

So you've got:

```
000uuuuu zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx as
00000001 11110101 00110100
```

Plug the bits in:

```
11110uuu 10uuzzzz 10yyyyyy 10xxxxxx =
11110000 10011111 10010100 10110100
```

Which in hex is `F0 9F 94 B4`.

---

To go the other way, from UTF-8 to code point, you check the most significant bits of the first byte to see how many bytes are used (this should be clear from the table above), then pluck out the relevant bits and put them together.

---

Bonus lineart:

```
000uuuuu zzzzyyyy yyxxxxxx as
00000001 11110101 00110100
   │││││ ││││││││ │││││││└────────┐
   │││││ ││││││││ ││││││└────────┐│
   │││││ ││││││││ │││││└────────┐││
   │││││ ││││││││ ││││└────────┐│││
   │││││ ││││││││ │││└────────┐││││
   │││││ ││││││││ ││└────────┐│││││
   │││││ ││││││││ │└─────┐   ││││││
   │││││ ││││││││ └─────┐│   ││││││
   │││││ │││││││└──────┐││   ││││││
   │││││ ││││││└──────┐│││   ││││││
   │││││ │││││└──────┐││││   ││││││
   │││││ ││││└──────┐│││││   ││││││
   │││││ │││└───┐   ││││││   ││││││
   │││││ ││└───┐│   ││││││   ││││││
   │││││ │└───┐││   ││││││   ││││││
   │││││ └───┐│││   ││││││   ││││││
   ││││└────┐││││   ││││││   ││││││
   │││└────┐│││││   ││││││   ││││││
   ││└─┐   ││││││   ││││││   ││││││
   │└─┐│   ││││││   ││││││   ││││││
   └─┐││   ││││││   ││││││   ││││││
11110uuu 10uuzzzz 10yyyyyy 10xxxxxx =
11110000 10011111 10010100 10110100
```